# Splitting year column into multiple columns (SAS,SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains records with one of the columns being a TAXYR. The column consists of both 2024 and 2025 records. I'd like to create a new table and split the column into two separate columns, TAXYR2024 and TAXYR2025 (each record has a letter status associated with it, among others). What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: Why? Wouldn't that make it harder to work with the data?  If you are making a report then use PROC REPORT and indicate that TAXYR is an ACROSS variable.

Comment: "each record has a letter status associated with it, among others" - how does this look?  Could you share sample data of your table?

Comment: And will it be okay if you get NULL values in between your entries for columns TAXYR2024 and TAXYR2025? I can think of one easy way but it will provide you NULL values in-between.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any example input or example output, or really explain what the new variables should contain.

Perhaps you just want them to be binary flags to indicate the same information that is in the TAXYR variable?

```
data want;
  set have;
  taxyr2024 = (taxyr=2024);
  taxyr2025 = (taxye=2025);
run;
```

Perhaps you wanted them to have the value of some other variable whose name you didn't name?  Let's say the other variable is named INCOME.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if (taxyr=2024) then taxyr2024 = INCOME;
  if (taxyr=2025) then taxyr2025 = INCOME;
run;
```

But I am not sure how either of these make it any easier to use the data than the original structure.

Comment: this helped once more, thank you Tom

Comment: I was not aware of PROC REPORT in sas